# Fill() only on the first line and with an additional condition

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I have data in which NA sometimes occurs

```
df <- read.table(text = "Czas                Energia Energia.2 Water
'2023-11-01 00:00:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA 
'2023-11-01 00:00:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.001
'2023-11-01 00:00:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.001
'2023-11-01 00:00:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.003
'2023-11-01 00:01:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.004
'2023-11-01 00:01:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.006
'2023-11-01 00:01:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.011
'2023-11-01 00:01:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.011
'2023-11-01 00:02:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.015
'2023-11-01 00:02:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.018
'2023-11-01 00:02:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.020
'2023-11-01 00:02:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.021
'2023-11-01 00:03:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.023
'2023-11-01 00:03:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.029
'2023-11-01 00:03:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.030
'2023-11-01 00:03:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA 
'2023-11-01 00:04:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.031
'2023-11-01 00:04:15'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.036
'2023-11-01 00:04:30'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.038
'2023-11-01 00:04:45'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.12" , 
header = TRUE
)
```

I want to replace NA, but only in the first line with the value below (I can do it using fill() .direction = "up"). However, there is an additional condition - the values should appear from line 6 at most. If NA appears in the first 6 lines, NA should remain in the first line.

For example, for the data below, NA in the first line replaces the value 1359.001

```
df <- read.table(text = "Czas                Energia Energia.2 Water
'2023-11-01 00:00:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA 
'2023-11-01 00:00:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA
'2023-11-01 00:00:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.001
'2023-11-01 00:00:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.003
'2023-11-01 00:01:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.004
'2023-11-01 00:01:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.006
'2023-11-01 00:01:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.011
'2023-11-01 00:01:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.011
'2023-11-01 00:02:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.015
'2023-11-01 00:02:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.018
'2023-11-01 00:02:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.020
'2023-11-01 00:02:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.021
'2023-11-01 00:03:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.023
'2023-11-01 00:03:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.029
'2023-11-01 00:03:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.030
'2023-11-01 00:03:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA 
'2023-11-01 00:04:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.031
'2023-11-01 00:04:15'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.036
'2023-11-01 00:04:30'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.038
'2023-11-01 00:04:45'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.12" , 
header = TRUE
)
```

For example, for the data below, the NA in the first row remains unchanged

```
df <- read.table(text = "Czas                Energia Energia.2 Water
'2023-11-01 00:00:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA 
'2023-11-01 00:00:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA
'2023-11-01 00:00:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA
'2023-11-01 00:00:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA
'2023-11-01 00:01:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA
'2023-11-01 00:01:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA
'2023-11-01 00:01:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.011
'2023-11-01 00:01:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.011
'2023-11-01 00:02:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.015
'2023-11-01 00:02:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.018
'2023-11-01 00:02:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.020
'2023-11-01 00:02:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.021
'2023-11-01 00:03:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.023
'2023-11-01 00:03:15'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.029
'2023-11-01 00:03:30'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.030
'2023-11-01 00:03:45'             4.08e13        373649997824                     NA 
'2023-11-01 00:04:00'             4.08e13        373649997824                   1359.031
'2023-11-01 00:04:15'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.036
'2023-11-01 00:04:30'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.038
'2023-11-01 00:04:45'             4.08e13        373653995520                   1359.12" , 
header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: `df[-c(1:6),]` gives you the rows 7+ of the df, so you can just do `df[-c(1:6),] <- df[-c(1:6),] |> ...rest of process`